# Databricks: Change the existing schema of columns to non-nullable for a delta table?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, schema, delta

I have currently a delta folder as a table with several columns that are nullable. I want to migrate data to the table and overwrite the content using Pyspark, add some columns and make them not nullable. I have found a way to make the columns in the pyspark df as non-nullable:

```
non_nullable_schema = StructType([
    StructField("column1", StringType(), nullable=False),
    StructField("column2", StringType(), nullable=False),
])

# Apply the new schema to the DataFrame
non_nullable_df = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, non_nullable_schema)
```

But it seems like after I write to the existing delta destination folder and load it again, it shows that the columns are nullable again after I print the schema
:

```
non_nullable_df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option("overwriteSchema", "true").save("/path/to/delta/files")
df_read=spark.read.format("delta").load("/path/to/delta/files")
df_read.printSchema()
```

Is there any way to change an existing schema in delta to not nullable using pyspark without creating a new delta table?